# How getting a json on the controller model and send it to c # mvc4

Tags: json, controller

controlador------------------------

private Products seminariolista = new Products();

public ActionResult actualizar(List viewmodelbacth)

{

List list = new List();

list = seminariolista.actualizar(viewmodelbacth);

return list;

}

modelo-------------------------------

public ActionResult actualizar(List viewModelBacth)

{

var productoslista = new Products();

try

{

using (var ctx = new ProyectoContext_())

{

foreach (Products product in viewModelBacth)){

productoslista = = ctx.Seminario.Where(x => x.id == product.id).SingleOrDefault();

if (!(productoslista = null))

{

productoslista.orden = product.orden;

productoslista.modal = product.modal;

}

}

ctx.SaveChanges();

}

}

catch (Exception)

{

throw;

}

return productoslista;

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F596B.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am from Peru, my English is not good, my question is:
I have a grid, and will edit the combobox and radio button with a single button to save all the data that would update the rows, and have reinforced the json, the controller sending the json and then the model and the model is where you insert the database, but I get error 500 when it reaches the controller, I took four days but can not find solution, thanks for your reply, in mi html:

Comment: $.ajax({
           
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("actualizar", "grilla")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(batch),
            //data: JSON.stringify( lista_),
            success: function (result) {

                $('#grid').trigger('reloadGrid');
            },
            
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('Error: '+ errorThrown);
                }
        });